# Jacobi Identity in de Sitter Superalgebra

Tags: supergravity, de-sitter-spacetime, superalgebra

In the book "*Supergravity*" (by D. Freedman and A. Van Proeyen) they talk about why $\mathcal{N}=1$ de-sitter superalgebra is impossible to construct (Section 12.6.1).

Basically de-Sitter algebra is a modification of flat space symmetry algebra with: $[P_{\mu}, P_{\nu}] = -\frac{1}{4L^2} M_{\mu\nu}$.

Then if we try to embed this into a superalgebra with say: $[P_{\mu}, Q_{\alpha}] = \frac{a}{4L} (\gamma_{\mu}Q)_{\alpha}$ with arbitrary "a" we see that the Jacobi identity involving $[P_{\mu},P_{\nu}, Q_{\alpha}]$ is not satisfied.

Whereas in the paper "*Construction of the de Sitter supergravity*"([arXiv:1602.01678v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01678)) the authors say:

> Super-dS algebras do exist for even $\mathcal{N}$ in 4 dimensions (and for other D $\le$ 6).

Which implies that having an R symmetry, somehow makes the above problem go away. My question is, how does that work out? Any reference is welcome.

**Note:** I tried to read W. Nahm's paper in which he classifies all the SUSY algebras. But that paper just has the list of algebras. If there's a reference that tackles the above problem in detail, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: [Pilch et al 1985](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103942287).